# Tiny additions to doubles appearing 8 places after decimal: Android

Tags: java, android, double

I'm still a bit of a noob regarding this. I'm puzzled about what's happening. I stored a 3.542 in a sqlite database. Checking the database with Firefox sqlite viewer confirmed this. Then I retrieved the value with the following code:

```
public double getCaffPer(String type) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(DRKTYPES);
    String[] columns = { MGCAFF };
    String[] selectionArgs = { type };
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = builder.query(ourDatabase, columns, TYPE + "=?",
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    float result = -1;
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getFloat(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Debugging revealed a value of 3.542 for result. But then later in my code I call this method:

```
double caff = helper.getCaffPer(typeName);
```

and it gives me 3.5420000553131104. I know this isn't much of a difference, but I'm puzzled as to why the stuff at the end is added. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because `result` is declared as a `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior occurs because you declare `result` as a `float` but `getCaffPer()` returns a `double`. Java does a silent conversion between the two types which introduces the difference in the output.

Comment: Declaring it as a float fixed the issue. But I wonder why all the junk is added at the end when converting to a double.

Comment: @MES Neither `double` nor `float` can store an *exact* value of a number. For details, I suggest you do some research about how floating point numbers are stored.